# Starting Automation on MS Edge Canary on MacOS

Tags: macos, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I downloaded the MS Edge Canary browser and I have placed the msedgedriver file in my PATH. When I pass my script "Edge" as browser name. It gives me following error:

> 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

However for macos it shouldn't look for this file.

P.S: I am using robot framework on PyCharm on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: which path that you store edge driver?

Comment: Please check that you had downloaded the correct version of web driver for your Edge browser on MAC OS. Make sure that you are referring to correct path. For testing purpose, try to pass 'MicrosoftEdge' browser name in your script. You can try to post your sample code we will try to check it.

Comment: @sidara usr/local/bin

Comment: @deepak It’s searching for .exe file... I have placed the correct file in folder but it looks for .exe file and i am on mac os

Comment: Not sure why it is searching for an .exe file. if you are sure that you had setup it properly and your code is correct than you can try to provide feedback to Microsoft site from where you had download that driver. You can also try to provide the detailed steps and sample code which you had followed. we will also try to make a test with it to check for the issue.

Comment: This looks like a mix of a problem with selenium's code (3.141.0) and Microsoft's driver (Release 82). 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' is hard coded in selenium's edge/webdriver.py. I tried passing `edge = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="msedgedriver")` (which is the macos webdriver from MS that I placed in my PATH) and that raises another error: `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found`. So 1. selenium (3.141) still assumes Edge is Windows only. 2. msedgedriver (Release 82) does not pass selenium's capability checks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. robot framework version: 3.2.1 in python 3.7.6 on macOs Darwin. Downloaded M Edge webdriver from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/  and put it in the PATH but still it is looking for .exe file.